# Is there another way to solve this problem?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was thinking about how to find the price of something before tax when you know the tax rate and the final price including tax, and I know that there's one way to do it, but I want to know the way to solve the problem when you're not adding like terms.

Here's the original equation I came up with:
x + x(.086) = 1.38

.086 is the tax rate and $1.38 is the final price.

I know that you can add like terms and then divide 1.38 by 1.086, but is there a way to solve the problem when you turn it into x(.086) = 1.38 - x? I know this is a slightly obscure question since there's already an established method, but I'm just wondering if there's another way where you're not combining like terms. Thanks!

Comment: Your alternative method is the same as the standard one you quote: it's the same linear equation in $x$ when you add $x$ to each side.

Comment: If the tax rate is $r$ and the initial price is $x$ and final price is $F$ then you will always have the final price of $F = x + r*x = x(1 + r)$ and $x = \frac F{1 + r}$.  You can always add the original to the increased to get $ ( 1 + r)$.  Always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x + x*r = x*(1 + r)$ Always.

And the follow 4 equations are always equivalent and you can always use whichever one is more useful.  They all say the *exact* same thing but what concept they emphasize may differ:

$x + x*r = x*(1+r) = F$.

$x = \frac F{1+r}$ and

$x = F-x*r$

$x*r = F - x$

$x$ is original price. $F$ is final price $x*r$ is how much tax you paid. $(1+r)$ is by what proportion the final price was compared to the original price.

All of those are mutually consistant, equivalent, and basically all say the exact same things.

===

So if you are told

$x*.086 = 1.38 - x$ you solve it like any other algebra question.

Add $x$ to both sides to get the $x$ to one side of the equation:

$x*.086 = 1.38 - x$

$x*.086+ x = 1.38 - x + x$

$x*.086 + x =  1.38$

Then factor out the common $x$.

$x*.086 + x = 1.38$

$x(.086 + 1) = 1.38$

$1.086*x = 1.38$.

then divide both sides by $1.086$

$1.086x = 1.38$

$\frac {1.086x}{1.086} = \frac {1.38}{1.086}$

$x =\frac {1.38}{1.086} \approx 1.27$.

Answer (score 1):

You can write the equation as $x=1.38-0.086x$ and use fixed point iteration.  Start with some guess at $x$, say $1$, and call it $x_0$.  Then the iteration is to write $$x_{i+1}=1.38-0.086x_i$$
and iterate to convergence.  It converges to two decimal places in three iterations and to the nine my spreadsheet displays after ten iterations.  A lot more work, but it is a useful approach for numeric answers to an equation you can't solve analytically.

Comment: I was in the middle of typing this very answer when yours appeared.  Nobody else seems to have taken the question seriously.